# a snapshot of what life was like…

Tags: phrase-usage, construction

The  book offers ***a snapshot of what life was like*** in Britain under the Romans.

Does that phrase sound fine by you?
I like its construction **but I’m not sure if it is correct**.

Thank you…

Comment: If you google the phrase **a snapshot of what life was like...** you will find that you are certainly not the first person to use it.

Comment: It is idiomatic and perhaps, as Ronald Sole implied, an over-used turn of phrase. Why do you doubt its validity?

Comment: No reason in particular. I wasn’t familiar with it. I’m learning,
Thank you,